# Maximum sum staircase complexity

Tags: algorithms

Given an $n \times n$ matrix of integers, I would like to find the optimal dividing line that maximizes the sum of the integers on the same side as the top left corner.  The dividing line should be connected and made up of only vertical and horizontal parts.  For example:

[image]

The complication is that the number of horizontal parts is restricted to be at most $k$, for some integer parameter $k$. In the picture above there are 4 horizontal parts. The line can start at any point on an edge and end at any point at a different edge.

Without this restriction I believe one can find the optimal partition using dynamic programming in $O(n^2)$ time.  How quickly can my version be solved?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this?  Can you credit the original source?

Comment: @D.W. It's my own problem. I would be very interested if it has been studied before.

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved in $O(n^2 k)$ time using dynamic programming.  Let $A[1..n,1..n]$ be the matrix.  Define $T[i,j,\ell]$ be the maximum possible sum of the top-left corner, for any dividing line that divides $A[i..n,j..n]$ using at most $\ell$ horizontal parts.  Then there is a simple recurrence relation for $T[i,j,\ell]$, e.g.,

$$\begin{align*}
T[i,j,\ell] &= \max(T[i+1,j,\ell)+A[i,1]+\dots+A[i,j],U[i,j,\ell])\\
U[i,j,\ell] &= \max\{T[i+1,j',\ell-1)+A[i,1]+\dots+A[i,j'] \mid j' < j\}).
\end{align*}$$

Notice that

$$U[i,j,\ell] = \max(U[i,j-1,\ell],T[i+1,j-1,\ell-1)+A[i,1]+\dots+A[i,j-1]).$$

Then, it is easy to fill in all entries of $T$ and $U$ in $O(n^2k)$ time, as long as you fill them in the right order.  Please check all of the details, as I haven't checked the details carefully.

Comment: If A = [[-1, 1], [1, 1]]  and k =2, I am trying to see how this would work. T[1, 1, 2] = max(T[2, 1, 2] + A[i, 1], U[1, 1, 2])  and U[1, 1, 2] = max(T[2, j', 1] + A[i, 1]). Is that right and what is j' in this case?

Comment: Following the expanded definition of U, what are the base cases?

Comment: @Simd, I have to let you work that out.